# Convert for of action to be cross browser compatible

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

So I'm using the below code to do some actions based on a change event, but the `for ( .. of ..)` call isn't supported in all browsers (IE, Edge, etc..) - What would be the best way for me to convert that?

```
var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('.rtd3_change');

function rtd3Confirmation() {
    if (document.querySelectorAll('.rtd3_change:checked').length) {
        formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = '';
        formWrapperConfirm.required = true;
    } else {
        formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = 'none';
        formWrapperConfirm.required = false;
    }
}

for (var inputElement of inputElements) {
  inputElement.addEventListener('change', rtd3Confirmation);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', rtd3Confirmation);
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Only IE doesn't support it. Edge does.

Comment: are you not using transpilers like [babel](https://babeljs.io/)?

Comment: I am, but when I convert it over,  it's has a `'Symbol' is undefined` error which is a whole new beast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the good old for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
  inputElements[i].addEventListener('change', rtd3Confirmation);
}
```

Comment: It's showing a `Unresolved variable or type inputElements` error @brandt.codes - Do I have to include `rtd3ChangeClass` as shown in the `for of` above? Here is what I had for that variable: `var rtd3ChangeClass = document.querySelectorAll(".rtd3_change")`

Comment: This is just a replacement for the 'for of loop'. The code before and after the loop should stay the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help @brandt.codes - With a added forEach polyfill, it's all finally working.